Docker Url is not accessible through localhost
Docker file
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["UserMicroservices/UserMicroservices.csproj", "UserMicroservices/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./UserMicroservices/UserMicroservices.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/UserMicroservices"
RUN dotnet build "./UserMicroservices.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./UserMicroservices.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "UserMicroservices.dll"]

Docker file :
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ChatService/ChatService.csproj", "ChatService/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ChatService/ChatService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ChatService"
RUN dotnet build "ChatService.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "ChatService.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ChatService.dll"]

Compose file
version: '3.8'

services:
  user-service:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}usersmicroservice:v1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: UserMicroservices/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - CONNECTIONSTRINGS__DEFAULTCONNECTION=Data Source=192.168.3.6,1433;Initial Catalog=UserServiceDB;User Id=******;Password=******
    ports:
      - "4202:80"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

  chat-service:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}chatsmicroservice:v1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ChatService/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "4203:80"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

networks:
  default:
    name: hudyio-network

Docker container is running but can't access the URL in a browser.
I'm using .NET 8


Can you use specific exported port 4203:8080 instead of 4203:80 and conflict doesn't really matter with ports in this situation but you might need to export those two services from different ports
